# Why is Java's TargetDataLine.read() so slow?

Tags: java, voip, javasound, pcm

I am developing a VOIP application that uses Java's built in `TargetDataLine.read()` method to store microphone input in a byte array buffer. However, this function seems to run for around 500ms longer than it should. Why is there this extra latency and are there any other methods that I can use to reduce the latency? I am using 16bit 40000Hz PCM signed.

All responses will be very much appreciated

Comment: What is it reading *from?*

Comment: @EJP I am getting the data from the microphone using `tLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, getAudioFormat()));`

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This is not a typical latency for the TargetDataLine.read(). The problem is most likely elsewhere.